# xml to treeview using dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net, xpath

I have an xml file with following structure:

```
<table name="tblcats">
    <row>
        <Id>3680</Id>
        <Industry>Associations</Industry>
        <ParentId>1810</ParentId>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Id>1592</Id>
        <Industry>Fortune 100</Industry>
        <ParentId>1810</ParentId>
    </row>
    <row>

</table>
```

I want to populate a treeview using this xml. I have created a dataset and sorted it and written following code:

```
   Dim xmlfile As String = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Industries.xml")
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        ds.ReadXml(xmlfile)

        Dim sortedRows As DataRow()
        sortedRows = ds.Tables(1).Select("", "ParentId")

        Dim XDoc As New XmlDocument()
        Dim XDec As XmlDeclaration = XDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", Nothing, Nothing)
        XDoc.AppendChild(XDec)

        ' iterate through the sorted data
        ' and build the XML document
        For Each Row As DataRow In sortedRows
            ' create an element node to insert
            ' note: Element names may not have spaces so use ID
            ' note: Element names may not start with a digit so add underscore
            Dim NewNode As XmlElement = XDoc.CreateElement("_" & Row("Id").ToString())
            NewNode.SetAttribute("Id", Row("Id").ToString())
            NewNode.SetAttribute("ParentId", Row("ParentId").ToString())
            NewNode.SetAttribute("Industry", Row("Industry").ToString())

            ' special case for top level node
            If CInt(Row("ParentId")) = -1 Then
                XDoc.AppendChild(NewNode)
            Else
                ' root node
                ' use XPath to find the parent node in the tree
                Dim SearchString As [String]
                SearchString = [String].Format("//*[@Id=""{0}""] ", Row("ParentId").ToString())
                Dim Parent As XmlNode = XDoc.SelectSingleNode(SearchString)

                If Parent IsNot Nothing Then
                    Parent.AppendChild(NewNode)
                Else


                    ' Handle Error: Employee with no boss
                End If
            End If
        Next


        ' we cannot bind the TreeView directly to an XmlDocument
        ' so we must create an XmlDataSource and assign the XML text
        Dim XDdataSource As New XmlDataSource()
        XDdataSource.ID = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()
        ' unique ID is required
        XDdataSource.Data = XDoc.OuterXml

        ' we want the full name displayed in the tree so 
        ' do custom databindings
        Dim Binding As New TreeNodeBinding()
        Binding.TextField = "FullName"
        Binding.ValueField = "ID"
        TreeView1.DataBindings.Add(Binding)

        ' Finally! Hook that bad boy up!       
        TreeView1.DataSource = XDdataSource
        TreeView1.DataBind()
```

but It fails here:

```
 SearchString = [String].Format("//*[@Id=""{0}""] ", Row("ParentId").ToString())
```

How can I fix this xPath to match my XML ? Please suggest how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing xpath as follows-->

`SearchString = [String].Format("//Id[.=""{0}""]/..", Row("ParentId").ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

The `@` sign is for checking for an **Attribute** value that matches.  Remove the `@` and try again.